# variable doesn't increment/decrement on my code

Tags: c#, messagebox

```
if (getchar == '+') {
    answer = getnum1+getnum2;   // if the random operation is add, it will add
    addtemp++;                 // <---- disregard this
    if (answer == getanswer)   //  the answer from my textbox which is
    {                         //  user-input it is stored on "getanswer"
        correct++;            // it is compared if its correct or wrong
        addcomp++;
    }
    else { wrong++; }
}
else if (getchar == '-') {
    subtemp++;
    answer = nextValue - nextValue1;
    if (answer == getanswer) {
        correct++;
        subcomp++;
    }
    else { wrong++; }
}
else if (getchar == '*') {
    multemp++;
    answer = nextValue * nextValue1;
    if (answer == getanswer) {
        correct++;
        mulcomp++;
    }
    else { wrong++; }
}
else if (getchar == '/') {
    divtemp++;
    answer = nextValue / nextValue1;
    if (answer == getanswer) {
        correct++;
        divcomp++;
    }
    else { wrong++; }
}
else if (getchar == '%') {
    modtemp++;
    answer = nextValue % nextValue1;
    if (answer == getanswer) {
        correct++;
        modcomp++;
    }
    else { wrong++; }
}
```

C# programming HELP! Now whenever i press the button "SCORES" it is a MessageBox.Show(correct or wrong) , the values are wrong. it sometimes increment corrected but just once or twice.Is there something wrong with my code?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ENTIRE CODE for @boncodigo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace A1_ALS_Noroña
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int minV=0, maxV=0,ques=0,tempques=1;

        int addtemp, subtemp, multemp, divtemp, modtemp;
        int addcomp, subcomp, mulcomp, divcomp, modcomp;
        int answer,getanswer;
        int getnum1, getnum2;

        char getchar;
        char[] select = new char[5];
        int count=0;
        int correct, wrong;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void bttnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bttnanswer.Enabled = true;
            grpbox1.Enabled = false;
            bttnanswer.Enabled = true;
            lblnum1.Visible = true;
            lblnum2.Visible = true;
            lbloperator.Visible = true;
            bttnstop.Enabled = true;
            bttnscore.Enabled = true;
            bttnstart.Enabled = false;


            Random random = new Random();
            int nextValue = random.Next(minV, maxV);
            int nextValue1 = random.Next(minV, maxV);
            lblnum1.Text = nextValue.ToString();
            lblnum2.Text = nextValue1.ToString();

            var rand = new Random();

            char num = select[rand.Next(count)];
            lbloperator.Text = Convert.ToString(num);
        }

        private void txtboxmin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            minV = Convert.ToInt32(txtboxmin.Text);
        }

        private void txtbxmax_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            maxV = Convert.ToInt32(txtbxmax.Text);
        }

        private void bttnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void bttnstop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("APPLICATION STOP! The application will restart.");
            Application.Restart();
        }



        private void bttnanswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tempques++;
            Random random = new Random();
            int nextValue = random.Next(minV,maxV);
            int nextValue1 = random.Next(minV, maxV);
            lblnum1.Text = nextValue.ToString();

            var rand = new Random();
            char num = select[rand.Next(count)];
            lbloperator.Text = Convert.ToString(num);
            lblnum2.Text = nextValue1.ToString();
            getnum1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblnum1.Text);
            getnum2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblnum2.Text);
            getanswer = Convert.ToInt32(txtbxans.Text);
            getchar = Convert.ToChar(lbloperator.Text);

            if (getchar == '+')
            {

                answer = getnum1 + getnum2;
                addtemp++;              
                if (answer == getanswer)  
                {                      
                    correct++;            
                    addcomp++;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
            }
            else if (getchar == '-')
            {
                subtemp++;
                answer = nextValue - nextValue1;
                if (answer == getanswer)
                {
                    correct++;
                    subcomp++;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
            }
            else if (getchar == '*')
            {
                multemp++;
                answer = nextValue * nextValue1;
                if (answer == getanswer)
                {
                    correct++;
                    mulcomp++;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
            }
            else if (getchar == '/')
            {
                divtemp++;
                answer = nextValue / nextValue1;
                if (answer == getanswer)
                {
                    correct++;
                    divcomp++;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
            }
            else if (getchar == '%')
            {
                modtemp++;
                answer = nextValue % nextValue1;
                if (answer == getanswer)
                {
                    correct++;
                    modcomp++;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
            }







        }

        private void txtbxques_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ques = Convert.ToInt32(txtbxques.Text);

        }

        private void chkbxtimer_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rdoeasy.Enabled = true;
            rdomed.Enabled = true;
            rdohard.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void chkboxAdd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (chkboxAdd.Checked == true)
            {
                select[count] = '+';
                count++;
            }
            else if (chkboxAdd.Checked == false) 
            {
                Array.Clear(select, 0, select.Length);
                count--;
            }

        }

        private void chkboxSub_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkboxSub.Checked == true)
            {
                select[count] = '-';
                count++;

            }
            else if (chkboxSub.Checked == false)
            {
                Array.Clear(select, 0, select.Length);
                count--;
            }

        }

        private void chkboxMul_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkboxMul.Checked == true)
            {
                select[count] = '*';
                count++;

            }
            else if (chkboxMul.Checked == false)
            {
                Array.Clear(select, 0, select.Length);
                count--;
            }

        }

        private void chkboxDiv_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkboxDiv.Checked == true)
            {
                select[count] = '/';
                count++;

            }
            else if (chkboxDiv.Checked == false)
            {
                Array.Clear(select, 0, select.Length);
                count--;
            }
        }

        private void chkboxMod_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkboxMod.Checked == true)
            {
                select[count] = '%';
                count++;

            }
            else if (chkboxMod.Checked == false)
            {
                Array.Clear(select, 0, select.Length);
                count--;
            }
        }

        private void bttnscore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct Answer"+correct);
        }




        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try to debug it?

Comment: At a guess, `getchar` is never one of `+-*/%`.

Comment: Show us how getchar is filled and how the MEssageBox is created.

Comment: @JanDarrenNoroña - English please. No idea what you are saying there.

Comment: @oded my getchar is a variable for storing lbloperator.Text

Comment: @Kuya John. i said i tried to debug it, but i think my code is wrong.

Comment: What NUMBER data type your answers and get answers are? e.g. if your answer is decimal and an integer division might result in a 0 when it is unable to have the decimal points... Other than that, are you able to show us the entire code as well? Also at the addition your variables are `getnum1+getnum2; ` but going forward they change into `nextValue`, `nextValue1`.... Why is that?

Comment: @JanDarrenNoroña can you post the whole code, maybe the error is not on the code you have posted.

Comment: @bonCodigo, i was debugging it, the values are all the same, the nextvalue is also my num1, and nextValue1 is my num2. OK I'll show you my entire code. I'll edit this post.

Comment: woa, my cyclomatic complexity meter just crashed...frankly, I am not surprised that code has a bug. Try to refactor it into smaller pieces, clearly labelled for what they do. Chances are that you will see the mistake yourself pretty soon.

Answer (score 1):

One thing in advance: I don't know where your bug is. Here's just a couple of tips that I think it would make sense if you think about them, in order to avoid similar bugs in the future:

If I had to review this code, my major issue would be with the amount of repeating code, where very similar multi-line long patterns are copied over and over. I think in the whole code you don't call any method, but implement stuff right away in the event-handlers, thereby repeating yourself and multiplying the potential for bugs. Let's look at this code:

```
if (chkboxSub.Checked == true)
{
    select[count] = '-';
    count++;

}
else if (chkboxSub.Checked == false)
{
    Array.Clear(select, 0, select.Length);
    count--;
}
```

apart from the bug with count when you have added several operators to the select-array, this code repeats several times. Let's extract the code into a method and make the bits that change parameterizable:

```
void AddOrRemoveOperator(bool isChecked, char operatorChar) {
  if (isChecked) {
    select[count] = operatorChar;
    count++;
  }
  else {
    Array.Clear(select, 0, select.Length);
    count--;
  }
}
```

Now you can call that method many times, e.g. like:

```
AddOrRemoveOperator(chkboxSub.Checked, '-');
```

Next point would be lack of .NET Base Class Library knowledge (BCL). E.g., wouldn't it be easier to use a `List<T>` instead of an array?

The above method becomes:

```
void AddOrRemoveOperator(bool isChecked, char operatorChar) {
  if (isChecked) {
    select.Add(operatorChar);
  }
  else {
    select.Clear();
  }
}
```

An Observation: All operators except the add one use the values nextValue, nextValue1 while the add one uses getnum1 and 2. Is that intended?

Short of extracting the code blocks in `bttnanswer_Click` into their own class, you can also extract the repeating code into a method:

```
 void PerformComparison(Func<int> answerProvider, 
    ref int operatorCount, 
    ref int operatorSpecificCorrectCount)
 {
    var answer = answerProvider();
    operatorCount++;
    if (answer == getanswer) {
        correct++;
        operatorSpecificCorrectCount++;
    }
    else {
        wrong++;
    }
 }
```

That code would still drive me mad (because the class you have programmed *lacks cohesion*), but we have fought code duplication. Now you can call the method e.g. like that:

```
if (getchar == '+')
{
  PerformComparison(()=>getnum1 + getnum2, ref addtemp, ref addcomp);
}
```

There are many techniques to morph code into forms that are more easily testable and maintainable (refactoring), we have only used *extract method* so far. For more techniques the book [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) is still highly recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a float precision issue (maybe your user is entering 3 and the program calculates 2.9999999). Debug your code and identify one case when it is not adding correctly.

Comment: Is that possible? All of my getnum1 and getnum2 are integers.

Comment: shouldn't be if everything is integer. You need to find a sample case.